# How to unit test an anonymous inner class created in the constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, anonymous-inner-class

Here is the class I want to test:

```
public class MyView extends FrameworkView {
    public MyView(Repository repository) {
        repository.addEventListener(event -> {
            refresh();
        });
    }
}
```

and its parent:

```
public class FrameworkView { 
    protected final void refresh() {
        // do framework magic to refresh the view
    }
}
```

I want to unit test MyView. I can use an ArgumentCaptor to get the listener (using Mockito):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Repository repository = mock(Repository.class);
    MyView instance = new MyView(repository);
    ArgumentCaptor<EventListener> listenerArgument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(EventListener.class);
    verify(repository).addEventListener(listenerArgument.capture());
    EventListener listener = listenerArgument.getValue();

    // call the listener to trigger the refresh() call
    listener.handleEvent(null);

    // now what?
}
```

The problem is that the `refresh()` method is in the super class (not under my control), and it's final, and has side effects which are very hard to verify. So I don't see how I can stub or override the `refresh()` method, nor how I can verify its behavior.

The only solution I can think of now is to move the `refresh()` call into a package-private method of MyView and stub that:

```
public class MyView extends FrameworkView {
    public MyView(Repository repository) {
        repository.addEventListener(event -> {
            doRefresh();
        });
    }

    void doRefresh() {
        refresh();
    }
}
```

And then the test would become:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Repository repository = mock(Repository.class);
    MyView instance = Mockito.spy(new MyView(repository));
    ....
    verify(instance, times(1)).doRefresh();
```

But I think this is ugly. Does anybody have ideas for a nicer solution?

Comment: I think your solution is ok since you isolated the behavior needed to be tested and considering refresh() is final. I am curious to see what other people will say.

Comment: That the method of interest is marked as final seems to be the big issue for me. I think you have a pretty good handle on the issue. From a unit testing perspective, really you should only be interested to verify that the method is invoked once, so you achieve that by adding the doRefresh() method. A different mocking toolkit like JMockit would open up the possibility to mock the final method if that's of interest--again the point of a unit test, though, would just be to verify the interaction with the dependency on the superclass.

Comment: Really, you shouldn’t write dozens of lines of testing code, to test a lambda expression consisting of less than twenty non-whitespace characters (sixteen, if you simplify it to `event->refresh()`), especially when the only thing to test, is, whether the lambda expression `event->{refresh();}` really invokes `refresh()`. In fact, introducing another delegate method, `doRefresh()`, for that, *raises* the chance of bugs (how do you test that `doRefresh()` invokes `refresh()` correctly? It has the same complexity as the lambda expression. *Don’t write test cases for a one-liner*.

Comment: I understand your point and agree with it. But just not testing this feels like giving up. Even though it's a one-liner it could be crucial behavior of the class, which I want to test for. Stubbing the artificial `doRefresh()` method indeed doesn't really solve the issue, but gets as close as possible. Final methods in super classes are just a PITA!

Comment: Re-reading my question of 2016, the answer is obvious to me: We need to accept that MyView and FrameworkView are part of one 'unit' to be tested. If the side effects of FrameworkView cannot be mocked or intercepted, then they cannot be tested directly, but maybe we can read the state afterwards and verify that it is refreshed. Forcing 'one-test-per-class' unit testing is not always useful (or feasible).